# Java Swing Not Rendering after JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I've created a custom JDialog With Constructor like this:

```
public class SampleMain  extends JDialog

public  SampleMain (MainFrame mf, String [] args){

    super (mf, "Choose a Folder" ,true );
    /*Here I Create the View*/
}
```

JDialog has a button with Action Listener:

```
class EnterListener implements ActionListener  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        /*Some Logic Here*/

        setVisible(false);
        dispose();


    }
}
```

I'm calling to this Dialog from another JFrame:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame
```

JButton Listener that calls the extended JDialog:

```
class TreePathListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String [] list = {tfUsr.getText() ,tfPas.getText() ,tfRepo.getText()};

        SampleMain sm = new SampleMain (MainFrame.this ,list );

        txtPath.setText(sm.getSelectedPath());

    }
}
```

Now for the Problem:
Before I click the View the extended JDialog JFrame looks like this:

[image]

After:

[image]

Any Idea how i can fix that ?

Thanks.

here Is a sample project: anyone can use that as a custom JDialog example with miglyout.

https://mega.co.nz/#!1EgQBTZQ!e299pFTNAK7OYA2lQA4Wg1crlozsVrdUIg1RiRcvgnI

EDIT:

I found the problem at the original project, I had this code on the extended dialog class.

```
static {
    try {
        String className = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(className);
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    }
}
```

Removing that fixed the problem.

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This is the SSCCE Everything Is relevant. If I'll delete any part of the question It will be had to understand what Is the problem and what might cause it.

Comment: That is NOT a SSCCE.  I can't compile and execute the code to see the described behaviour.

Comment: I'll create tomorrow an executable version and post it here. Thanks for the willingness to help!

Comment: I've uploaded the sample project, I found the problem thanks to you. I got a custom code with a problematic static section. removing that static block solved the problem.